# Rails render wrong match html tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

there are some `</div>` tag in my post content, so when I render the post body by:

```
<%= simple_format(post.body) %>
```

The format will be in dreadful disorder.

So how to do is the right way ?

Comment: Do you mean that `post.body` has `</div>`'s, but not the accompanying `<div>`'s and that messes up your layout?

Comment: right, that's my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of the `</div>`'s in your `post.body` like this:

```
<%= simple_format(post.body.gsub('</div>', '')) %>
```